# Resizing an image in MATLAB and its effect

Tags: image, matlab, resize, effect

If I resize an image in `MATLAB`, what effect will that have on the original image. Say for instance I have an image of size `437x167` and I want to resize it to `256x256`. Will there be any details that will go missing from such operation?

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly you doing it? Seems that in the rows dimension you have to lose some information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about image processing.

Comment: Off course u will loose details when down scaling images. Otherwise you could re-size images into e.g. 1 x 1 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly you mean: "what are the results on an image after using matlab's built in function [imresize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html)?" by looking at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) of imresize you can see that you can choose what algorithm you want to use through the parameters of imresize. the best answer can be found by googeling the respective algorithms and reading what is the data loss caused by each of these algorithms